# Trying to use django-bootstrap-modal-forms as confirm modal, the post method is being called twice

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use the BSModalReadView as confirmation modal. So, I created the following class:

```
class PopulateOntologyView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalReadView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'modalPopUp/populateOntology.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Project was Read.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ontoSecReqRule:SecConProjects')

    def get_object(self):
        print("processing")
        user = self.request.user
        project = Project.objects.filter(user=user)
        x = project.filter(projectName=self.kwargs['project'])
        return x.first()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("mypost")
        createUCModel(str(self.request.user), self.kwargs['project'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('ontoSecReqRule:SecConProjects'))
```

I created a post method, so that when the user click the populate button the createUCModel(str(self.request.user), self.kwargs['project']) is then run.

Template for the main page.

```
<main class="mainContent">
        {% include "modalPopUp/_modal.html" %}
        <div class="card" id="maincontent">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Semi-Modeled Use Cases</h3>
                <span class="float-left total_count">{% if show_pageitems %} {% show_pageitems %}{% else %} Modeled Use Case: {{myUseCase|length}}{% endif %}</span>
                <button type="button" class="populate-project btn btn-dark float-right" name="button">
                                    {% icon 'cogs' %} Populate Ontology
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
{% block extrascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".populate-project").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'useCaseExtract:PopulateOntology' view.kwargs.project %}"});
       });
  </script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

Template for the modal:

```
  <form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

 <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Populate Ontology</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    Do you want to populate the ontology?
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Populate</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

When the user click the "Populate" button the post method will be called. However, the post method is being called twice.

These are the sequence of requests being processed once I clicked the "Populate" button:

```
mypost
[13/Jun/2020 10:35:03] "POST /useCaseExtract/PersonalInvestmentManagementSystem/PopulateOntology/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Jun/2020 10:35:03] "GET /ontoSecReqRule/SecConProjects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16143
[13/Jun/2020 10:35:03] "POST /useCaseExtract/PersonalInvestmentManagementSystem/PopulateOntology/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
mypost
[13/Jun/2020 10:35:03] "GET /ontoSecReqRule/SecConProjects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16143
[13/Jun/2020 10:35:04] "GET /django_popup_view_field/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
```